# Is it viable to make liquid potassium ferilizer through dissolving very small amounts of potassium chloride in water

Tags: botany, nutrition, experimental-design, growth, experiment

I wasn't able to find fertiliser online that was simply potassium chloride and I didnt want to source my potassium chloride solution from potassium sulphate or other general NPK fertilisers for my experiment on the effect of varying K+ concentrations on a plant. maybe 50,100,250,1000 ppm solutions. Or is there another element or component of fertilisers, perhaps compounds that lead to nurtient intake that I am overlooking in my methodology

Comment: If you have potassium sulfate (or carbonate) you can precipitate using Calcium salts (nitrate etc). Not all, just most.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the issue here is the chloride not the potassium.  Potassium chloride is very soluble in water. but you could be killing your crops/garden when you spray it on.

Most plants do not tolerate much Chloride ion.  With a limit of 500mg/kg of chloride in soil you will not be able to use much of this stuff.

that's wny potassium phosphates are much more desirable.  the phosphate will be consumed by the plants.